# Can we use DBCP 2 or Tomcat connection pool for distributed transactions in Spring? Can these connection pool be used along with JOTM or Atomikos?

Tags: spring, distributed-transactions, apache-commons-dbcp, atomikos, tomcat-jdbc

Initially i was using different transaction manager for multiple data sources. But i had problem with managing rollback on all data sources if one of the data sources has transaction failure.I want to manage multiple datasources with single Transaction manager in Spring. So i opted for using JOTM or Atomikos. Both these transaction manager uses **XA Connection pool(org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource)**. But in my project i was allowed to use only **DBCP 2(org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource)  or Tomcat Connection Pool(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource)**. Is it possible to use either of this connection pools with JOTM or Atomikos. Please someone help me on this along with configuration example. Below is my configuration details,

<

```
bean id="jotm" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="jotm" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource1" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown"> 
    <property name="dataSource"> 
    <bean class ="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource " destroy-method ="shutdown"> 
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jotm" /> 
    <property name="driverName" value="${jdbc.d1.driver}" /> 
    <property name ="url" value = "${jdbc.d1.url}" /> 
    </bean> 
    </property> 
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.d1.username}" /> 
    <property name = "password" value="${jdbc.d1.password}" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource2" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.pool.StandardXAPoolDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="dataSource"> 
    <bean class ="org. enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource " destroy-method ="shutdown"> 
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jotm" /> 
    <property name="driverName" value="${jdbc.d2.driver}" /> 
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.d2.url}" /> 
    </bean> 
    </property> 
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.d2.username}" /> 
    <property name = "password" value ="${jdbc.d2.password}" /> 
    </bean>
```

Also do help if any other possible ways to achieve this.